# Cannot make URL mapping using Pretty Faces 3.3.2, JSF 2.0, JBoss 6.1.0 final

Tags: jsf-2, mapping, jboss6.x, prettyfaces

I'm experiencing problem with Pretty Faces URL mappings.

I have one managed bean with the following mappings:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@URLMapping(id = "search", pattern = "/search/", viewId = "/search/search.xhtml")
```

And it works fine when I go to http://ip/search/?keywords=word.

However, when I try to change mapping pattern, I got an error.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@URLMapping(id = "search", pattern = "/search", viewId = "/search/search.xhtml")
```

I expect that the http://ip/search?keywords=word gives the same response as the link above, but unfortunately I get 404 HTTP error.

search.xhtml is in WebContent/search/ folder of Web project deployed on JBoss 6.1.0 final.

The interesting thing is when I use JBoss 5.1.0 and Pretty Faces 3.2.0 and JSF 1.2, the mapping works fine (of course, all mappings are done via XML configuration in this case).

I would appreciate any answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between the folder name, in which the *.xhtml* file is stored, and the *pattern* value, so if the folder name is the same as the pattern value, the mapping doesn't work.

In my case, I had to change the folder name **search** to **search_pages** and the mapping started to work fine - it is possible now to visit *http://ip:port/search?keywords=keyword* and to get appropriate results.

I don't know if this behavior is assumed for Pretty Filter, but, for me, it looks a little bit strange.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason SO stopped sending me notifications, so I didn't see your replies until now :( Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried version 3.3.2 of PrettyFaces? There were some bugs fixed there. Also, have you tried a complete refresh of the page and browser cache? Sometimes redirects are cached by the browser.

Also, if worse comes to worse, I suggest debugging com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.PrettyFilter and see what is going on inside.

Also make sure that you don't have any other URL-rewriting configuration that would affect the mapping, like a trailing slash append or something like that.

Comment: I'm using 3.3.2 version, and it doesn't work, but with 3.2.0 version it works fine.

Comment: Can you, please, look at my answer. Maybe it is a bug within the Pretty Filter. Tnx!